# How memory management in Windows different than Linux? Does Windows OS support paging or segmentation?

Tags: windows, linux-kernel, operating-system, paging, memory-segmentation

I am curious to know about the difference between memory management in Windows and Linux.Does Windows OS support paging or segmentation?

I trying to understand, If all processes cumulatively uses all RAM on Windows machine then every user is prevented even from log in to the system but that is not the case with Linux systems.

**So how it's achieved in Linux system?**

Comment: Windows will swap out to disk (the memory swap file) read more about Windows Memory management here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2160852.  Linux can also use virtual memory: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1

Comment: On high level they work essentially the same, they both support pagination, potentially backed by space on disk. Probably the most evident difference is (was?) that Windows does not do overcommitting. For the logging in bit, clearly you never tried to log on a Linux machine that is badly thrashing (although if a process is seriously hogging memory the OOM will probably kill it, a thing that on Windows doesn't happen).

Comment: Segmentation and paging aren't mutually exclusive. An OS can use both. Also in case of x86/x64 "segmentation" as you're using it isn't very well defined. From App viewpoint, it could mean that OS sets some segment registers to different base/limits from others (eg FS on Windows) but the whole linear address space is addressable via "default" seg registers (CS/DS/SS). Or OS could point CS/DS/SS to distinct ranges. Beyond what App sees OS can further use segmentation to swap in different programs or parts of programs - Windows doesn't do this. Answer: paging and some aspect of segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the recent posts, Windows 10 also supports compressing of the RAM. that means, before Windows tries so SWAP out memmory on hard drive, it will try to compress the RAM